# How to add multiple columns in a table with HSQLDB?

Tags: hsqldb

I have been trying to use the ALTER TABLE command with HSQLDB to add 2 columns to a table but with no luck. I know MySQL and other systems support it but why doesn't HSQLDB support it? Perhaps I'm using the wrong syntax, I don't know. I also know that I could add it one-by-one but my application requires the addition of 1000 columns and it is too slow to do it one-by-one.

The reason that I'm using HSQLDB is that I need to use it in file-mode. I have also tried [SmallSQL](http://www.smallsql.de/), but it is much more slow than HSQLDB.

Comment: A table with a 1000 columns is usually a sign of a bad database design. Can you explain us why you think you need so many columns? And why can't you just create them with the initial `create table` statement?

Comment: Regarding the question: "*but why doesn't HSQLDB support it*". The answer is surprisingly simply: because no one has implemented it yet. It's an open source project, so if you really need that, you can add this feature.

Comment: Have you heard of big data or large scale systems in general? 1000 columns is not a bad design, there is not such rule. Our column names are not pre-defined. The data come from observations and our users define the column names based on the things they collect data for. So, yes, we have users that have thousands things to observe.

They might observe 100 things, then they can edit the observation and add another 500 things.

Perhaps we will go with MongoDB, it supports even millions of "columns".

Comment: Yes I have heard of large scale systems. I maintain several databases with 1TB and more data. None of them has tables with more than 200 columns. What you are describing sounds as if you actually want a properly normalized one-to-many relationship. If your customer observers thousands "things" you should insert a thousand _rows_ into the database. And I doubt that HSQLDB is the proper choice for "big data" in the first place.

Comment: The data come from answers to questions (like interviews). The questionnaire is dynamic, each user designs his/her own one. Each question is a variable and we store it in a column. So the number of questions is not known to us. We should be able to support thousands. Each questionnaire is filled in by thousands of people, and every filled-in form is a row for us. So, someone might answer X questions, but another person might answer X+Y questions, so we need to add Y columns to the table.

Comment: We could store all that in a key-value structure, like a big JSON object and put that as a BLOB in the table., but we need to run complex queries on that data for post analysis and can't do that with BLOB's.

Comment: Still doesn't sound like you need thousands of columns. You might consider Postgres instead of HSQLDB btw. It supports a very efficient key value store (`hstore`) and JSON and I'm sure Postgres will be much more suitable to handle "big data" than HSQLDB is. But I don't see the need for either a key/value nor a JSON solution - this can be handled with a properly normalized model as well .

Comment: What do you mean? To split the data into multiple tables and use foreign keys to join them (with one-to-one relations)? And what will be the criteria about where to split the data? Just the number of columns per table?

Comment: You only need three tables for this: questionaire, question and answer (an probably a table with user information). Something like: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0a4e5/1 No idea what you mean with "*split the data*" though

Comment: Thank you for your time on this. But then we need to create a VIEW of all the data in a questionnaire, so that each question ID is a column the rows contain the answers for a specific questionnaire ID. You can post your solution as an answer to this thread (not as comment), so that I could accept it and close the thread.

Comment: I don't understand why you would need a view that transposes the rows into columns - you should do that in your application, not in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need thousands of columns for this. This is a standard one-to-many relationship between three tables: `questionaire`, `question` and `answer`:

```
create table questionaire 
(
  id              integer not null primary key,
  customer_name   varchar(100) not null
);

create table question 
(
  id                integer not null primary key,
  questionaire_id   integer not null references questionaire,
  question_text     varchar(20000),
  sort_order        integer
);

create table answer 
(
  question_id   integer not null references question,
  answer_text   varchar(20000),
  user_name     varchar(50) not null,
  primary key (question_id, user_name)
);
```

In reality you wouldn't actually store the users's name in the `answer` table. If you have named users that log in, you probably also need a `user_account` table and the `question` table would reference the `user_account` table.

You can easily query this model without the need to revert to a key/value store or JSON

To get all questionaires from a customer

```
select *
from  questionaire qu
where customer_name = 'Some company';
```

Get all questionaires and the number of questions per customer

```
select qu.customer_name, 
       count(distinct qu.id) as num_questionaires,
       count(q.id) as total_questions
from  questionaire qu
  join question q on qu.id = q.questionaire_id 
group by  qu.customer_name;
```

Get all answers for a questionaire from a specific user

```
select q.question_text, a.answer_text
from answer a 
  join question q on q.id = a.question_id 
  join questionaire qu on qu.id = q.questionaire_id 
where qu.id = 1
  and a.user_name = 'Marvin'
order by q.sort_order;
```

A bit more complicated, but probably still fast enough even with thousands of questions and answers: find users that haven't answered all questions

```
select aq.user_name, aq.questionaire_id, aq.answered_questions, tq.num_questions
from (
  select a.user_name, q.questionaire_id, count(*) as answered_questions
  from answer a 
    join question q on q.id = a.question_id 
  group by a.user_name, q.questionaire_id
) aq join (
     select questionaire_id, count(*) as num_questions
     from question
     group by questionaire_id
  ) tq on tq.questionaire_id = aq.questionaire_id
where aq.answered_questions < tq.num_questions;
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0a4e5/1

---

You also shouldn't try to transpose the rows for each question (or answer) into column in SQL - you *will* eventually hit some limits of the number of columns the database can manage. Relational databases were designed to handle rows, lots of rows - not "thousands of column". Transposing rows to columns is typically done in the presentation layer of your application (or e.g. using a Pivot function in a spreadsheet)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is really helpful. I forgot to mention though that each "answer" can be of any type, not just text. It can be a number, a date, a GPS coordinate, a binary file, or a multiple choice. This is the reason we use different columns for different questions. I just had forgotten. This is the reason that we have thousands of columns. Moving to no-SQL would solve the scalability problems. We are in a process of evaluating HBase.

Comment: @melios: you can store multiple types of answers in the `answer` table by having different columns (with different types). But I have a hard time understanding why you would evaluate HSQLDB for this in the first place. For one HSQLDB is probably not a good choice if you are serious about "big data". Postgres or any other server based DBMS would be a **much** better choice. And secondly you have clearly made up your mind that a relational solution is not going to work (although you seem to lack the experience in that area) so why waste your time with finding a relational model?

Comment: Our platform is already running on a clustered MySQL server which hosts a few hundreds of applications and the total size of the data are more than 10T. The platform is a set of 8-9 components. My initial issue with HSQLDB was just a tiny tiny sub-project in the whole business. One of the components needs a local file database, not a database server and we were evaluating such databases, like SmallSql, SQLite, HSQLDB and H2 Database. I don't want to prove my experience to anything, I'm more than 18 years in software development and decisions depend on many more things than my experience alone.

Comment: Just to let you know, I already solved the original issue by using H2 Database. The big data issue is about the core database server (MySQL), totally unrelated with the HSQLDB one. It is a platform I inherited and it was created 10 years ago with the inflexible model of thousands of columns. My big experience in Hadoop/HBase/Cassandra/MongoDB has made the decision-makers thinking about moving to no-SQL databases that perform much better in clustered mode with big data. I don't need experience in RDBMS anymore, because all that will soon be in the past.